# Using a constexpr generated type in a library API

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, api-design, boost-hana

I attended a talk from Romeo Vittorio this weekend at MeetingCPP Berlin. In his library [ECST](https://github.com/SuperV1234/ecst/), he implemented an [option_map](https://github.com/SuperV1234/ecst/blob/master/include/ecst/mp/option_map/basic.hpp) on the top of Boost.Hana in order to "build" the settings that will be used to create the actual type:

```
constexpr auto s =                        // .
    ecst::settings::make()                // .
        .allow_inner_parallelism()        // .
        .fixed_entity_limit(entity_limit) // .
        .component_signatures(make_csl()) // .
        .system_signatures(make_ssl())    // .
        .scheduler(cs::scheduler<ss::s_atomic_counter>);
```

... the rest of the code is [here](https://github.com/SuperV1234/ecst/blob/master/example/pres_code.cpp#L919)

I find the API really nice, because we create a type with function calls: we actually do meta-programming as "normal" programming, which I like. Also, for complicated templated types, it is much easier to develop with this approach (on the library-side): again, only *constexpr* methods and functions, no template at all.

Now, my question is about the usage of this API.  The problem with this approach is that the type hidden behind *auto* is actually very complicated and not "API-user friendly" as it has been generated by the constexpr functions which I think is fine: the user doesn't need to know the exact type, he just wants to use it, right? But how will he use this class as a property of a class, as *auto* cannot be used as non-static property?

```
static constexpr auto ctx = ecst::...;
using context_t = decltype(ctx);
context_t _context;
```

or

```
decltype(ecst::...) _context;
```

are not elegant solutions in my opinion. Having mandatory to use *decltype* does not seem nice to me.

Another solution would be to simply pass the this *auto* type as templated parameter to a class - this is what ECST does in the [example](https://github.com/SuperV1234/ecst/blob/master/example/utils/pres_game_app.hpp#L16) - but again, it constraints a lot the user, as he will have to template his entire code in order to use a library.

What do you think? Is there an elegant solution here?

Comment: Does just using `s` from your first block of code not work?

Comment: @JasonRice no, you can't use *auto* if the property is not *static*. This piece of code works because it is in a function definition - *main* in this example.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the *property of a class* part. Does the user define `s`?

Comment: @JasonRice yes, the user defines *s*